# How to verify Play Integrity API token using the Google Client API for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-integrity-api

I'm trying to verify whether my token generated in Play Integrity is valid. For now I could decrypt my token. However, I didn't find API if it exists to verify that token. Could you please point me if it possible. Thank you in advance.

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonFile);

var service = new PlayIntegrityService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "MyApp",
    });

var requestBody = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest
{
    IntegrityToken = integrityToken
};


var request = service.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(requestBody, packageName);

var result = request.Execute();
```

Packages:

```
"Google.Apis" Version="1.60.0"
"Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.60.0"
"Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1" Version="1.60.0.2926"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see **PlayIntegrityService** making only verdicts such as:
**appLicensingVerdict, deviceRecognitionVerdict, appRecognitionVerdict**. It doesn't make any verifications, so you should do it on your own in code. For more information about verdicts see: [Work with integrity verdicts](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict)